# Secure access to 3rd party API from a Javascript app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, security

I am creating a web app in Angularjs which displays data from a 3rd party API (json). This is not a free API, I have to pay based on the amount of calls made.

I am given an API key which I call like this:
https://apiservice.com?key=1234567&p1=x&p2=y

I want to ensure that my api key is used only by my web app, so I created a proxy on my server. Now my angular app calls my server like this:
https://myserver.com/myapiproxy/?p1=x&p2=y , the server makes the call to the api using the key that is kept on the server, and returns the json data to the client. This way the key is kept secret.

However there is currently nothing to stop somebody else from calling "myapiproxy" and get the data.

Is there a way to ensure that only my app gets the data and that others can not make calls to the api on my expense?

I searched for a few hours and I couldn't find a truly secure answer. HTTP referer is not a good answer because it can be easily spoofed.

Comment: On your server you can make this call once you have a session. To have a session you will have to login which is a username password. I think your api is behind some authentication.

Comment: @Cyril The web app is publicly available. A visitor doesn't need to be logged in to use it.

Comment: I do not think it is possible to ensure that your API is only called from your angular app without using client authentication (see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42586/ensure-web-service-only-accessed-by-authorized-applications, for instance). However, you could do some means of abuse detection, e.g. limit the request rate for connected clients or even display a captcha if the user attempts too many requests.

Comment: @Thylossus Many thanks for the info and the link. Unfortunately it seems that probably you are right

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **JSON Web Tokens** - https://jwt.io/
It is a good way to secure your calls. It has angular module - https://github.com/auth0/angular-jwt

When user loads your app you can provide a token jenerate on the backend and store it in local storage.
Than on each api call you can check if this token is authentic.

Comment: Thanks, but can JWT be useful in my case where the app can be accessed by all visitors, not just those who log in?

Comment: Yes. Every visitor would receive his own token. And you can check this token on backend so you would know than it is your app user. This token would live for certain amount of time and even if someone steals it, it would expire. But you have to check `Host` header to make sure that someone calls your api from your own frontend.

Alternatively you can setup auth0 - https://auth0.com/ they are prety cool, has free plan and allows users to sign in with social providers or paswordless auth.

Comment: Unfortunately requiring visitors to sign in to view the content is not an option in my case. The host header, like referer, can be spoofed, but I guess it is better than nothing. Maybe I will combine that with a limit on the requests coming from the same IP.